# CSS, centering links inside div

Tags: css

how can I center my links like this? They all are centered inside a `div`, but they begin from the same distance.

```
i am link 1
i am a longer link than link 1
i am a short link
we are all centered in div
```

If I apply `text-align: center`, I get:

```
         i am link 1
i am a longer link than link 1
      i am a short link
   we are all centered in div
```

Thank you ;)

I have a table:

`<td valign='top'><a href='{url}' title='{title}' target='_blank'>{anchor}</a></td>`

The links need to be centered in my way, each in its own `td`. Not sure it's possible.

Comment: Please include a full demo? Are you looking for shrinkwrapped centering? If so use `inline-block`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the links in another `<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">` to group them together.

http://jsfiddle.net/NcEpe/1/

**Edit** for dynamic widths: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Comment: thought of that myself, but i cant use fixed width

Comment: See here for dynamic widths: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Answer (score 24):

If you need shrinkwrapped centering, apply `inline-block` on the things you want centered. Then `text-align:center;` on the parent.

You'll need to probably have a workaround for IE, but as you haven't posted code I won't go into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align: left;`

Comment: i have a div, and i need the links to be centered, but all of them be like in the first order

Answer (score 0):

Do this: nest a left-aligned div in a center-aligned div.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div style="text-align:left; width:300px;">
        Content<br />
        Longer Content<br />
        Really long Content<br />
        Content<br />
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Addition:

CSS lovers everywhere will condemn me for suggesting that you could replace the inner div with a table, which would remove the need to specify a fixed (or percentage) width.